# how to pass php POST parameters into .load() php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

my code

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.up').click(function() {
$('#postbox').load("uploader.php" );
    return false;

        });
        });
```

html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Wybierz plik: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Wyślij" class="up"/>
</form>

<INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="długość" NAME = "długość"><INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE           ="wysokość" NAME = "wysokość">
<INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="jakość [1-12]" NAME = "długość">


<div id="postbox">
</div>
```

now, my uploader.php file opens in #postbox, but i need to add parameters too

I just need php file uploader.php to display in #postbox div, after form parameters are passed to it. Now it displays "error while uploading the file", because it doesnt get file to upload.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Add parameters to what? Try some research: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2):

`.load` allows you to send data as the second argument.

```
$('.up').click(function(e) {

    $postbox = $('#postbox'); 
    if( $postbox.find('form').length === 0 )
        $postbox.load('uploader.php');
    else 
    {
        var form_values = {};  
        $.each($postbox.serializeArray(), function(i,v){ form_values[ v.name ] = v.value  })
        $postbox.load('uploader.php', form_values ); 
    }
  e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Comment: so i should do something like    ('#postbox').load("uploader.php", { var1: 'MAX_FILE_SIZE', var2:"uploadedfile"} );

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the data. So you want to send those variables to `uploader.php` ?

Comment: yes, i want to do the same as i would press send button in my form

Comment: it works now just like submit button - it displays in new window, instead of #postbox div - i don't get why

Comment: Sonia, either `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: when added e.preventDefault() before if statement, it displays okay, but uploader.php don't work correctly (i get error message - unsuccesful upload). return false changes nothing...